# ClassCastException when overriding a super's method (Comparable<T>)

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I did search but couldn't find a similar problem. I'm sorry if this is duplicated. I write a regular queue method and try to extends it to have a priority queue. I don't understand why I can only insert if I use the super class' method, and not the code in the sub class while storage[n] is a Comparable and data is a Comparable too. If I try to do that in the sub class, a ClassCastException will be thrown. Did I do anything wrong?

**RegularQueue.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RegularQueue<T> {

    protected int capacity;

    protected T[] storage;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    RegularQueue(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        storage = (T[]) new Object[this.capacity];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Queue{" +
                "capacity=" + capacity +
                ", storage=" + Arrays.toString(storage) +
                '}';
    }

    void insert(T data) {
        storage[0] = data;
    }
}
```

**PriorityQueue.java**

```
public class PriorityQueue<T> extends RegularQueue<Comparable<T>> {

    PriorityQueue(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }

    // This doesn't work
    @Override
    void insert(Comparable<T> data) {
        storage[1] = data;
    }

    // ---> This works fine.
    //    @Override
    //    void insert(Comparable<T> data) {
    //        super.insert(data);
    //    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>(5);
        q.insert(1);
        System.out.println(q.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing this ClassCastExpression because in RegularQueue you are using the non type-safe assignment `storage = (T[]) new Object[this.capacity]`. In PriorityQueue you are using `Comparable<...>` as type argument for `T` of RegularQueue. It is therefore known at compile time that this `T` must at runtime be `Comparable` or a subtype of it. Thus the compiler emits `Comparable[]` casts inside PriorityQueue every time you access `T[] storage` to enforce this.
The issue is now that `storage` is not actually of type `T[]` but only of type `Object[]` which is causing the ClassCastException you are seeing. This occurs when accessing the field in any way, even `storage.length` triggers it.

The reason why you are not seeing this exception in the `insert` method calling `super.insert` is that it does not directly access `storage`. Only the super implementation does this which however does not perform any casts since inside of RegularQueue the type of `T` is unknown at compile time.

The solution is to not declare `storage` as `T[]` but instead use `Object[]` since that is the actual type.

Someone else reported this as bug to the JDK team but the report has (as expected) been resolved as "Not an Issue". However Stuart Marks, one of the JDK developers, explains in [his comment](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8249950?focusedCommentId=14357191&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14357191) on the report in depth (and probably better than this answer) the underlying issue. I highly recommend reading it.

Comment: The thing is, the compiler doesn't actually need to cast `storage` to `Comparable[]`, because the only thing `storage` is used for is to set one of its elements, and that can be done on an `Object[]`. The compiler chooses to insert a cast on `storage` whenever it is used in `PriorityQueue` even though we do not use the fact that `storage` is a `T[]`, and this compiler decision is acceptable, but not mandatory. It is possible that another compiler won't insert a cast here.

Answer (score 0):

### This answer will try to supplement on Marcono1234 answer.

Using Eclipse Class File Editor, we can see in the class file
`RegularQueue.class`

```
// Signature: <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;
public class RegularQueue {
  ...
  // Field descriptor #8 [Ljava/lang/Object;
  // Signature: [TT;
  protected java.lang.Object[] storage;
  ...
  // Method descriptor #56 (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  // Signature: (TT;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  void insert(java.lang.Object data);
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  getfield RegularQueue.storage : java.lang.Object[] [19]
    4  iconst_0
    5  aload_1 [data]
    6  aastore
    7  return
  ...
```

`PriorityQueue.class`

```
// Signature: <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>LRegularQueue<Ljava/lang/Comparable<TT;>;>;
public class PriorityQueue extends RegularQueue {
...
  // Method descriptor #19 (Ljava/lang/Comparable;)V
  // Signature: (Ljava/lang/Comparable<TT;>;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  void insert(java.lang.Comparable data);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  getfield PriorityQueue.storage : java.lang.Object[] [22]
     4  checkcast java.lang.Comparable[] [26]  //<-- reason for ClassCastException
     7  iconst_1
     8  aload_1 [data]
     9  aastore
  ...
```

1. `checkcast` only exists in `PriorityQueue`, and not `RegularQueue`
2. It is checked for `java.lang.Comparable[]` against `storage` as erasure of `Comparable<T>` is `Comparable`, so `storage` is of type `Comparable[]` in the view of `PriorityQueue`.

In addition
`ClassCastException` will also throw, for

- `PriorityQueue<T> extends RegularQueue<Number>`
- `PriorityQueue<T> extends RegularQueue<String>`

`ClassCastException` will not throw (`checkcast` will disappear), when the type/erasure of the type argument is `Object`.

- `PriorityQueue<T> extends RegularQueue<T>`
- `PriorityQueue<T> extends RegularQueue<Object>`

### Solution

As suggested by Marcono1234,

> The solution is to not declare storage as T[] but instead use Object[] since that is the actual type.

For better type safety and readability, I suggest to make `storage` as private field also, and provide `setStorage` and `getStorage` method:

```
protected void setStorage(int index, T data) {
    storage[index] = data;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected T getStorage(int index) {
    return (T) storage[index];
}
```

As we can see in following example,

```
public class PriorityQueue<T> extends RegularQueue<Comparable<T>> {
...
    @Override
    void insert(Comparable<T> data) {
        setStorage(1, new Object()); // Compile error
        // following is allowed if storage is protected, error only occur when casting the value to Comparable<T>
        // storage[1] = new Object();
    }

    public Comparable<T> getByIndex(int index) {
        return getStorage(index);
        // Need to repeatedly cast when using storage value
        // return (Comparable<T>) storage[index];
    }
...
```

Reference:
[Reference Type Casting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1)
[The Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set - checkcast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.checkcast)